# How can I center an ActivityIndicator within the screen?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

How can I center an ActivityIndicator within the screen? My current code is:

```
Column {
    Row {
        ActivityIndicator {
            anchors.leftMargin: units.gu(10)
            running: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`anchors.centerIn: parent` is the solution:

```
ActivityIndicator {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    running: true
}
```